# How do I use `@Count` variable in my query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have following SP, I pass a parameter of count to my SP to get specific number of records.

But how do I use `@Count` variable in my query?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetRandomWords1]

    @Count int

AS
BEGIN

    SELECT * From Words

END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming SQL Server 2005+, use [TOP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetRandomWords1]
  @Count int
AS
BEGIN

  SELECT TOP (@Count) * 
    FROM Words

END
```

TOP is supported on SQL Server 2000, but using the brackets is not -- you have to use dynamic SQL on SQL Server 2000 for equivalent functionality.

Comment: Thanks, I am using SQL Server 2005.

Comment: For SQL2000, you don't need to use Dynamic SQL.  You can do: "Set RowCount @Count".  Just make sure you unset the rowcount when you are done with "Set RowCount 0".  This should ONLY be used with SQL2000, because the TOP clause is the preferred method for SQL2005 and up.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT TOP(@Count) * From Words ORDER BY NEWID()
```

Judging from your SP name it seems you want a random words back from your `Words` table.

Comment: Yes, exactly, I want random words. I will post another question related to that shortly. :)